# How to embed string in a background image?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a scratch card looks like

[image]

Basically I have a gray layer to scratch and it will reveal the red image.

Now I have set up the canvas and ctx is for the gray layer, but the background is fixed.
I want to have the "12345" be a variable to embed in the background,
which means I can have different number in the background image.

Here is the function I have for the scratch card.
(addEventlistener is just used for scratching the gray layer)

```
function bodys(height,width){

    var img = new Image();  
    var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');         
    canvas.style.position = 'absolute';  
    img.addEventListener('load',function(e){  
        var ctx;
        var w = width, h = height;

        var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft, offsetY = canvas.offsetTop;             
        var mousedown = false; 
        function layer(ctx){                 
            ctx.fillStyle = 'gray';                 
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);             
        }   
        function eventDown{
                        ...
        }   


        canvas.width=w;             
        canvas.height=h; 

        canvas.style.backgroundImage='url('+img.src+')';//here is the background image I use              
        ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');         
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        layer(ctx);               
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';     

        canvas.addEventListener{
                             ...
        }

    });
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text